# ExtJS 6 Rest Proxy where JSON Data Object is ID

Tags: json, rest, api, extjs, extjs6

I'm hoping someone can guide me on how to deal with this json data structure.

Here's an example of that: (I have zero control of this data)

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "thing 01",
        "attributes": {
            "color": "red",
            "brand": "ACME"
        } 
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "thing 02",
        "attributes": {
            "color": "blue",
            "brand": "ACME"
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm confused about how to get the records using the `reader`

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Thing', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'

    fields: [
        { name: 'name' },
        { name: 'attributes', type: 'auto' }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://example.com/api/things',

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: ??? // <--- How should this work?
        }
    }
});
```

I've wondered if there's a way to do something like...

```
rootProperty: '[id]'
```

Also is there a way to specify the ID when it is the data object? Maybe somehow using the `idProperty` config on the Model?

Should I use the reader.format method? That would seem a little gross...

Any ideas are apreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `rootProperty` config is for setting the root of all the data, not for each record. Also, I have not found a `reader.format` method in the ExtJS 6 [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EXACT question is already answered [here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261182-How-to-implement-custom-JSON-reader).

You should implement a custom reader and override the [`getResponseData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.reader.Json.html#method-getResponseData) method.

```
Ext.define('MyReader', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    alias: 'reader.myreader',

    getResponseData: function(response) {
        var data = this.callParent([response]);

        //do stuff here

        return data;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah thank you! Somehow I never found that on the Sencha forums. This will help a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

Write a custom reader class:

```
Ext.define('MyReader', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    alias: 'reader.myreader',

    config: {
        transform: function (data) {
            var ret = [],
                key, o;

            for (key in data) {
                o = data[key];
                o.id = key;
                ret.push(o);
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('Thing', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: ['name', 'attribute'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data1.json',

        reader: {
            type: 'myreader'
        }
    }
});
```

Example [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qj7).